# Weighted least squares estimator variance using noisy weights

Tags: covariance, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

I have a linear system with uncorrelated, heteroscedastic noise, $Y \propto \mathcal{N}(Xβ,Σ)$ where $Σ$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $σ_{ii}^2$. The MLE is given by weighted least squares (WLS) with weights $W = Σ^{-1}$,

$\hat{β} = (X'WX)^{−1}X′WY$

with estimator variance

$(\hat{β})=(X'WX)^{−1}$

Suppose I only have access to a noisy estimate of the weights, say
$\hat{w_{ii}} \propto \mathcal{N}({σ_{ii}^{-2}},s_{ii}^2)$. Is it possible to estimate the increase in estimator variance from using WLS with noisy weights?

Note, I understand that iterative weight estimation techniques (eg. IRLS) may converge to the MLE with it's ideal WLS variance in the large data limit, but that's outside the scope of my question.